# Magento 2 - billing address not changed

Tags: magento2, address

following code:

```
<?php
namespace UV\Adressen\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class LieferadresseEditObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $customerRepository;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)    
    {

        /*
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $orderRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->create();
        print_r(get_class_methods($order)); exit;
        $addressRepository->save($billingAddress);
        */

        $address = $observer->getEvent()->getAddress();
        if($address->getAddressType() == 'shipping') {
            error_log("Das ist eine Lieferadresse");
            $order = $address->getOrder();  
            #print_r(get_class_methods($order)); exit;
            $order->setBillingAddress($order->getShippingAddress());
            #$order->setShippingAddress($address);
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $orderRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository');
            #print_r(get_class_methods($orderRepository)); exit;
            $orderRepository->save($order);
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

Why is the billing address not being changed to shipping address?
They should be equal after the code has been executed.
Thanks!

Comment: what event you are  using?

Comment: sales_order_address_save_after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use save() function.

> $shippingaddressData = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();
>
> unset($shippingaddressData['entity_id]);
>
> unset($shippingaddressData['parent_id]);
>
> $order->setBillingAddress->setData($shippingaddressData);

**instead of**

```
    $order->setBillingAddress($order->getShippingAddress());
    #$order->setShippingAddress($address);
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $orderRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository');
    #print_r(get_class_methods($orderRepository)); exit;
    $orderRepository->save($order);
```

Comment: That is not working! But thanks for the effort.